# Can't show <pe:ckEditor/> on my XHTML page

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I'd like to integrate pe:ckeditor to my XHTML page.
After googling, I found this helpful link
 **www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/multipleEditors.jsf**

The Bean class is:

```js
package com.esprit.util;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean  
@ViewScoped  
public class EditorController implements Serializable {  
  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20111020L;  
  
    private String content;  
    private String secondContent;  
    private String color = "#33fc14";  
  
    public EditorController() {  
        content = "Hi Showcase User";  
        secondContent = "This is a second editor";  
    }  
  
    public void saveListener() {  
        content = content.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");  
  
        final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Content",  
                    content.length() > 150 ? content.substring(0, 100) : content);  
  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
  
    public void secondSaveListener() {  
        secondContent = secondContent.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");  
  
        final FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Second Content",  
                secondContent.length() > 150 ? secondContent.substring(0, 100) : secondContent);  
  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
  
    public void changeColor() {  
        if (color.equals("#1433FC")) {  
            color = "#33fc14";  
        } else {  
            color = "#1433FC";  
        }  
    }  
  
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

The page XHTML is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
    <body>
 <h:form>
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  
            <pe:ckEditor id="editor" 
    value="#{editorController.content}" 
           toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
                <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.saveListener()}" update="growl"/>  
            </pe:ckEditor> 
     <br/>  
            <br/>  
            <pe:ckEditor id="secondEditor" 
               value="#{editorController.secondContent}" 
                      toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
                <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.secondSaveListener()}" update="growl"/>  
            </pe:ckEditor>
 </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The added this to file web.xml:

```html
 <context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.primefaces.extensions.DELIVER_UNCOMPRESSED_RESOURCES
    </param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After running my project: I got this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GkHe.png).
As you see, I didn't have the same editor as displayed by the tutorial: I have an Editor without Header.

Have you please any idea about solving this. Any proposition is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: show your code ,so that we can help you more

Comment: Hello @argaPK , thanks a lot for your attention, I made change on my question, could you please take a look ?.Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sir @ArgaPK for your quickly reply, but now, I can't show any thing after running, I got a white page. I made some changes on my question, if it's possible could you please take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: first just add toolbar attribute and remove the dependency which i have tell you in the answer.

Comment: Yes Sir, I added the toolbar attribute and I removed all the jars except **resources-ckeditor-6.0.0.jar** but the xhtml page is empty now and on console of WildFly, I got the warning presented on my question. Thanks Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional to the attribute `toolbar` that @ArgaPK mentioned, you have to:

- Verify that those required jars exist:

  - commons-io-2.4.jar
  - commons-lang3-3.5.jar
  - gson-2.2.4.jar
  - primefaces-6.0.jar
  - primefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar
  - resources-ckeditor-6.0.0.jar
- Update your XHTML by adding `<h:head/>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
   <h:form style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
         <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  
         <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{editorController.content}" toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
          <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.saveListener}" update="growl"/>  
         </pe:ckEditor>
         <br/>  
        <br/>  
         <pe:ckEditor id="secondEditor" value="#{editorController.secondContent}" toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
            <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.secondSaveListener}" update="growl"/>  
       </pe:ckEditor>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saria for your help, I forgot <h:head/>, now it works as well.

Comment: The primefaces-extensions and resource-ckeditor's versions should be the same of primefaces ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `toolbar` attribute

```
 <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  
    <pe:ckEditor id="editor" value="#{editorController.content}" toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
  <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.saveListener}" update="growl"/>  
    </pe:ckEditor 
    <br/>  
   <br/>  
    <pe:ckEditor id="secondEditor" value="#{editorController.secondContent}" toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']]">  
   <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{editorController.secondSaveListener}" update="growl"/>  
  </pe:ckEditor>
```

and add the following dependency also:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

see this helfull link 
[Getting started with primefaces extensions](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: Thanks Sir for your help, I added the required dependencies as presented on my question. now after running I obtain the screenshot shared on my question, if you don't mind could you please take a look ?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: remove all the jars except primefaces and primefaces extensions

Comment: Have you successfully used primefaces extension before implemented this example??

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your reply. No, it's the first time that I used primefaces extension. I remove all jars except primefaces and primefaces extensions, I obtained the editor without header exactly as I shared on my question. I didn't know why. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: now you have to add the dependencies,  i have updated the answer with the dependencies.

Comment: Hi Sir, I only add the two jars **rimefaces-extensions-6.0.0.jar** and **resources-ckeditor-6.0.0.jar**, and there's an exception I shared it on my updated question, if you have enough time, could you please take a look?. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Hi Sir, In my opinion, to solve this exception, I have to add **primefaces-6.0.jar**, but I encounter another exception _Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils from [Module "deployment.sample2.war:main" from Service Module Loader]_ .To solve this, I have to add the jars **commons-lang3-3.5.jar** , **commons-lang3-3.5-javadoc.jar** , **commons-lang3-3.5-sources.jar**, **commons-lang3-3.5-tests.jar** and **commons-lang3-3.5-test-sources.jar**. So, now I obtain the editor without header like the begin.

Comment: well this is may be issue from Jboos settings, try h:body instead of body in your xhtml and also make sure you don't use parenthesis when calling a method for e.g; listener="#{editorController.saveListener}"

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks a lot for your kindness, I tried <body> <form> then <h:body> <h:form> then <body> <h:form> then <h:body> <form> then I eliminate <form> and only I put <h:body> then <body>, but I still have the same result: an editor without header.

Comment: Hi Sir, I do that with the navigators: FireFox, Google Chrome and IE . Using Eclipse Neon instead of JBoss developers Tools and ApacheTomcat 7 instead of WildFly10, but unfortunately, Igot the same previous result.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Sir @ArgaPK for your help.

Comment: @Elisabeth it's a pleasure to help you however when i was telling you to add h:body and h:form , i didn't recognize that you don't have h:head tag which is necessary because primeFaces uses it to include the necessary JS/CSS code for the Ajax works and fancy look'n'feel.

Comment: Hello Sir @ArgaPK, yes you're right, excuse me Sir and sorry for this mistake, but on my code that I published on my question, I didn't made `h:head`, I thought that since you didn't tell me about its absence, so it's not necessary to put `h:head`. sorry again and thanks a lot for your help Sir.